# Google Sheets formula for unique values across columns

Tags: google-sheets

I'm familiar with the [`UNIQUE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093198?hl=en) function in Google Sheets and how it works on rows (see Examples 1 & 2 below).

Is there a function in Google Sheets that operates similarly on columns?

In Example 3 below, `UNIQUE` behaves as expected by treating this as a single unique row.

[image: Examples 1,2]

I've worked around this by using `TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE()))` (see Example 4), however would like to know whether there's a built-in solution.

[image: Examples 3,4]

Comment: There's not built-in solution AFAIK. Maybe try a Pivot table (but maybe not the best fit) ? or a simple script ? either solution will always be much worse than a simple transpose -> unique -> transpose

Answer (score 0):

Google Sheets doesn't have a "built-in feature" that return unique column values. Your workaround (using TRANSPOSE) is the way to do it.

Reference

[Google Sheets function list](https://support.google.com/docs/table/25273?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

With data in the first row:

```
=transpose(unique(transpose(A1:J1)))
```

[image]